# Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 on AMD Ryzen 2500U with Radeon Vega 8 Gfx

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, amd-processor, aspire

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 (18.04.1 will try tomorrow) onto Acer Aspire A315-41-R8XR. I have unpacked iso file to my flash and booted to grub successfully, but when I select "Try Ubuntu", I just get black screen and that's all. I have also tried to select "Install Ubuntu", but I get many errors:

[image]
<sup>**Google: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [migration/1:15]**</sup>

Windows 8.1 works fine, although it was already on the disk from another notebook, so, I think, it is not a power supply problem.

I've seen many such posts in the internet. It seems that people lost Ubuntu on Ryzen with Vega...

How to fix? May be use newer kernel? How to do it?

---

Comment: I still have issues with Linux Mint 20..and amd ryzen 3000 series.

Answer (score 3):

> My solutions: 
>   In my case, i edited `quiet splash` to `nosplash` (delete the `quiet`) and viola! it works.

Story:
Just recently installing Ubuntu 18.04 in along Win 10 (dual boot) in my HP Envy x360 13 AMD Ryzen 5, probably just the same with your Laptop. After struggling several hours trying all the solutions i found in many forums, but no luck. 
It seems that the solutions, depends on what error is occured when you install Ubuntu. 
in my cases, it said: 
[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gry1t.jpg)

Several things i've tried , but failed:

1. add `nomodeset`

   add `noacpi=off`

   add `amdgpu.dpm=0`

btw, do not forget that, if you install your Windows in UEFI, then u must install Ubuntu in UEFI mode too (cmiiw). UEFI - UEFI, Legacy - Legacy.

Answer (score 2):

First, boot using nomodeset as kernel parameter.
To do that boot in grub press `e` then add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash` then press F10 to boot.

If you are in legacy mode then select options and then check nomodeset.

Then upgrade to latest mainline kernel, or kernel newer that 4.19.0, and reboot.

Kernel 4.19.0 included with support for Ryzen mobile series and Vega graphics, however implementation is not yet complete - you will experience random freezes at least once a day.

Comment: I am using kernel 5.0.6 and the problem is still there. The laptop freezes every few hours and requires a hard restart which is annoying.

Comment: @AftabNaveed There was no problem for me like that, 5.0.6 (i m using 5.0.0-8) have even better support for ryzen. My laptop does not freezes at all on 19.04 or 18.10 either however there are freezing problems in 18.04 LTS. My laptop can handle workloads of 12-16 hours without freezing.

Comment: I am using Elementary OS 5 Juno which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but I manually went and updated the kernel to its latest version, the distro is working without any issues but it did not resolve the freeze issue :-( I am using Lenovo e485

Comment: Same issue with kernel 5

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, there is some error in BIOS, I followed instructions from this article:

http://kulminaator.blogspot.com/2018/06/linux-on-amd-ryzen-2500u-powered-laptop.html

in grub menu while booting press "e" to edit booting parameters and edit as specified in the link.

It worked for me. Good luck! ;-) D.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, insert the Ubuntu ISO image and open file explorer. Locate the boot folder and open the Grub config file with NotePad++. Edit the bootline of Try Ubuntu and/or Install Ubuntu :
Locate the linux line,**add a space** at the end and type **iommu=soft** .
Save, wait and exit. This change is permanent and it allows you to boot and compile custom Kernel (Ubiquity hot fix).

Example for Mint Tessa Compatibility Mode bootline:

```
linux    /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper xforcevesa iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} ramdisk_size=1048576 root=/dev/ram rw noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll -- iommu=soft
```

NB On Ryzen 2700U here, Linux ISO's will boot that way only.

```
cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-050000rc7-generic root=UUID=b6976dd1-ba78-4edc-9b49-4af79a979223 ro iommu=soft quiet splash vt.handoff=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue while trying to install any linux distributions in my new Dell inspiron 15 5000 5575.it also had the same AMD Ryzen 5 2500u processor and radeon vega 8 mobile integrated graphics.. i tried all the above methods but nothing worked for me.i asked in several showrooms and service centres to install linux.but they all said kali can't be installed in amd radeon combo.sometimes ubuntu can be done.

i tried :
      nomodeset
      acpioff
      make usb boot in various types
      tried all command line and grub  mode methods
      no graphics and safe modes

atlast i decided to update my bios.i downloaded and installed latest bios update for my dell pc which also noted that it enables the linux compatibily of my laptop .. DO IT WITH YOUR OWN RESPONSIBILTY!! and after bios uodate .. now all the linux distros work very smoothly.and i use a dualboot of ubuntu 19.04 and windows 10 .. i also checked if i can install kali and parrot.it also works.

Answer (score 1):

when booting to installation media, select <kbd>E</kbd> for edit, then replace quiet and splash with:

```
noapic nosplash irqpoll
```

Once booted and installed, you will need to do the same thing on `/etc/default/grub` and then run `update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had much better results using the latest Linux kernel (5.1) - though not using Ubuntu - but this is probably the most practical solution.

According to https://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-MP2-I2C-Linux-5.2

5.2 will bring further stability for Ryzen.

Answer (score 0):

Add these parameters to the boot option:

```
ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2
```

Press E to modify the boot option when you are inside GRUB.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHNpr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below solution and thank me later.

None of the solution worked for me i am using Ryzen 5 3500U. I have every parameter combination, used rufus, uneetbootin etc etc.

**Working solution and simple one USE `Fedora Media Writer` to create bootable image (ubuntu 18.04.3) and it will work like charm.**

No need to edit the boot parameter etc etc.