# Ubuntu on New computer with MSI b450 board and RYZEN 3600 - Problems with IOMMU

Tags: 18.04, grub2

I have had troubles installing Ubuntu on a new computer with an MSI B450 board and a RYZEN 5 3600.

First tried with Ubuntu 20.04 then downgraded my stick to 18.04 but still unsuccessful at first.

I finally managed to do it with 2 different SO threads :

[Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 on AMD Ryzen 2500U with Radeon Vega 8 Gfx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078568/unable-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-amd-ryzen-2500u-with-radeon-vega-8-gfx)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519758/amd-vi-completion-wait-loop-after-a-failed-install-of-arch-linux-on-a-blank-ssd

I had to add to my grub : `nosplash` `nomodeset` `noacpi=off` and from the latter thread `iommu=off`

Then I have been able to install UBUNTU 18.04 properly on my SSD.

Yet I have now to manually add `iommu=off` when booting.. or Ubuntu will not launch and I will get a purple blank screen.

I guess I should tweak my GRUB for good.
Yet I am not even sure what IOMMU is for ? and if `iommu=off` is the actual solution.. I have read Iommu was about the graphics (my graphic card is indeed an AMD Radeon 550 2GB).

I really don't care the graphics as I bought this graphic card just to be able to connect a screen to the computer (I don't play games). Yet I'd like to know if adding `iommu=off` will somehow snowball to other parts of the computer / decrease performance or create instability whatsoever .

Comment: Did you check with the vendor for any firmware updates?  I'd expect the 20.04 kernel would be more current than the 18.04 kernel (for awhile at least until a hwe update). Check inxi output (-C shows cores/threads) -- some acpi switches force only using one core.

Comment: Hi @ubfan1 It seams the hyperthreading is working good, I can see the 12 cores. Also I have learnt more about Iommu: it helps passing a graphic card performance to a virtual machine. As I don't do this at all I will leave the Grub with `iommu=off`. I couldn't find anywhere in the BIOS any mention to Iommu. And I have updated back to Ubuntu 20.04 also. It works like a charm and boots much fatser than 18.04. So all good so far.